# Application of Rice's Theorem

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, decidability

How can I prove, by applying Rice's theorem, that the language L is undecidable?

$L = \lbrace \alpha : M_{\alpha}(x) =x^2 \,\,\, \forall x \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace^* \rbrace  $

I think this is a direct application but I don't fully understand the theorem, nor how to formally write out the answer.

In my notes I have Rice's theorem written as: Let $R$ be the set of all functions of the form $ f:\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^* \cup \lbrace \perp \rbrace $ where $ \perp $ means that the Turing machine does not halt. Then let $ C $ be a non-empty proper subset of $ R $. Then the language $ \lbrace \alpha : M_{\alpha} $ corresponds to a function $ f \in C \rbrace $ is undecidable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Proof_sketch

Comment: Can you state the theorem you're applying? Which of the premises are you not sure hold?

Comment: @vadim: That's a proof of the theorem itself, which is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not sure about the whole theorem really, nor how to apply it to this example.

Comment: @lostAtLife: The first step is to find out what the theorem says, then. Do you have a statement of it in your textbook. Find it and quote it in your question.